# How to compute this contour integral with a modulus?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Evaluate the integral: 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {\omega e^{-2i\omega t}}{(\omega_0^2-\omega^2-\frac{\gamma}{m}i\omega)^{2}}d\omega$$
With $\frac{\gamma^2}{4m^2}>\omega_0^2$.

I solved the denominator and I have the roots:
$$\omega=-i\frac{\gamma}{2m}\pm i\sqrt{\frac{\gamma^2}{4m^2}-\omega_0^2}=ik^\pm$$

Then the integral becomes:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {\omega e^{-2i\omega tx}}{(\omega-ik^+)^{2}(\omega-ik^-)^{2}}d\omega$$

I am stuck here and do not have any idea for solving this integral. Please help me.

Comment: Use the standard "combo" of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).

Comment: Thank for your comment I got an answer. Thank a lot